# Wikipedia and Wikidata don't agree on pageid

Tags: wikipedia, wikidata

Looking for the pageid of [Le Havre Libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Havre_libre) I queried Wikidata and got the following

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&format=json&titles=Le_Havre_libre&sites=enwiki|frwiki&origin=*

{
    "entities": {
        "-1": {
            "site": "enwiki",
            "title": "Le_Havre_libre",
            "missing": ""
        },
        "Q3223483": {
            "pageid": 3077366,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Q3223483",
            "lastrevid": 480198576,
            "modified": "2017-04-30T13:53:38Z",
            "type": "item",
            "id": "Q3223483",
            "labels": {
                "fr": {
                    "language": "fr",
                    "value": "Le Havre libre"
                }
            },
            "descriptions": {},
            "aliases": {
                "fr": [
                    {
                        "language": "fr",
                        "value": "Havre Libre"
                    },
                    {
                        "language": "fr",
                        "value": "Le Havre Libre"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "claims": {
                ...
            },
            "sitelinks": {
                "frwiki": {
                    "site": "frwiki",
                    "title": "Le Havre libre",
                    "badges": []
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "success": 1
}
```

So I thought the `pageid` would be `3077366`

However neither https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=3077366 nor https://fr.wikipedia.org/?curid=3077366 lead to the right page!

From Wikipedia, I know that the actual `pageid` is `1649668`.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the pageid for wikidata: https://www.wikidata.org/?curid=3077366

To get the Wikipedia pageid, you need to use the page title and language from the wikidata API response in a query on the wikipedia API: https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Le%20Havre%20libre&format=json

That gives you the Wikipedia pageid:

> {"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"1649668":{"pageid":1649668,"ns":0,"title":"Le Havre libre"}}}}

Which gives the correct page: https://fr.wikipedia.org/?curid=1649668

Comment: ok; not really intuitive to have the same name for 2 different things